# PHP ladp_search() method returning empty array

Tags: php, search, filter, active-directory, ldap

I have a Red Hat running Apache + PHP, and I'm using the ldap_connect() method to connect to an Active Directory (Windows Server computer) on our LAN. The problem is, I'm probably using the ldap_search() method incorrectly, because I'm getting an empty array. Here is my code:

```
            if ($ldapbind) 
        {
            $ldap_dn = "CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain";
            $filter = "(&(objectclass=person)(samaccountname=$username))";              
            $my_search = ldap_search ($ldapconn, $ldap_dn, $filter);                            
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $my_search) or die ("erro get_entries");
            var_dump ($entries);
        }
```

Could someone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: What does `$username` contain? If it's Active Directory, make sure that it doesn't include the domain. Also, do you get any results if you just search for `objectclass=person` ?

Comment: I would also verify that the user you are authenticated as have the rights to retrieve users. You could also quickly test if you are searching correctly using the `ldapsearch` command line utility.

Comment: Thank you Ben and Bertold for the reply! I figured out the problem. After "fixing" the string "CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain", it worked! I was using these generic values and didn't realize before.